# Groupby for value before previous row

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

```
fruit   year     value 
apple   1950      2
apple   1951      3
apple   1952      3
apple   1953      4
apple   1954      5
apple   1955      4
banana  1950     333
banana  1951     335
```

How do i add a boolean if the value is lower than the value for the row above, per fruit? And if so the average of the previous 5 years

```
Expected Output
fruit   year     value  lower_than_before  5 year avg
apple   1950      2
apple   1951      3
apple   1952      3
apple   1953      4
apple   1954      5
apple   1955      4       True                 3.4
banana  1950     333
banana  1951     335
```

Comment: 5 year average relative to ?

Comment: the 5 year average before that boolean row per fruit. Here 5+4+3+3+2=17. So 17/5 = 3.4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
g = df.groupby('fruit')
df['lower_than_before'] = g['value'].diff().lt(0)
df['5 year avg'] = g['value'].apply(lambda x: x.rolling(5).mean().shift().where(df['lower_than_before'].cummax()))
df
```

Output:

```
    fruit  year  value  lower_than_before  5 year avg
0   apple  1950      2              False         NaN
1   apple  1951      3              False         NaN
2   apple  1952      3              False         NaN
3   apple  1953      4              False         NaN
4   apple  1954      5              False         NaN
5   apple  1955      4               True         3.4
6  banana  1950    333              False         NaN
7  banana  1951    335              False         NaN
```

Comment: Sorry is it possible to do the 5-year average after a True as well?

Comment: In my sample data, there's no year after 1955, but in principle it would be the average value from 1956 to 2000

Comment: "boolean array expected for the condition, not object"

Comment: @asd check for typo... that appears to be an error to what is going the `where` part of these statements.  df['lower_than_before'] should be a boolean series.

Comment: @ScottBoston awesome, I was thinking what would be the best way to tackle the relative 5 year avg but your approach works really well.

Answer (score 1):

Use shift function and handle the NaN, something like this:

```
df['lower_than_before'] = np.where((df.value - df.value.shift(1)) < 0, True, '')

df['5 year avg'] = np.where(df.lower_than_before=='True', df.value.rolling(window=5, min_periods=0).mean().shift(1), '')
```

Output:

```
    fruit  year  value lower_than_before 5 year avg
0   apple  1950      2                             
1   apple  1951      3                             
2   apple  1952      3                             
3   apple  1953      4                             
4   apple  1954      5                             
5   apple  1955      4              True        3.4
6  banana  1950    333                             
7  banana  1951    335
```

Comment: Thanks! Sorry is it possible to do the 5-year average after a True as well?

Comment: Yep, try this code:  df['5 year avg'] = np.where(((df.lower_than_before=='True') | (df.lower_than_before.shift(1)=='True')), df.value.rolling(window=5, min_periods=0).mean().shift(1), '')

Comment: Hmm the 5 year after doesn't seem to give the correct answer for some reason

Comment: @asd In the row_index=5 the previous 5 yr average should be 3.4 & in row_index=6 the it should be 3.8 which matches the output of the code.

Comment: In my sample data, there's no year after 1955, but in principle it would be the average from 1956 to 2000

Comment: @asd give this code a try: df['5 year avg after'] = np.where(df.lower_than_before=='True', df.value.shift(-5).rolling(window=5, min_periods=0).mean(), '')